# Can I use a Dynamic Routing Protocol in this scenario?

Tags: bgp, ospf, vrf

We are going to have potentially 50~ VRFs which will each be segregated customers.

We will have a VOIP LAN, and Print LAN, that all VRFs need access to. Currently I am having to create leaked routes on the switch, but this is a huge admin PITA.

Can I use OSPF to share that route to all VRFs (given this will all be happening on the same switch?).

i.e.

For every VRF routing table, I have a static route:

```
ip route vrf NAME 1.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 VLAN_PRINT
```

Then in the global routing table, a route back to every VRF:

```
ip route VRF_LAN 255.255.255.0 VRF_VLAN
```

As you can imagine, this leads to 100s of static routes on this single core switch, can I simplify this with some form of dynamic routing protocol?

Switch is a `Dell N4032 (L3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with Dell routers to know if you can have address families in OSPF. But even if you can, OSPF is a poor choice, because it's difficult to filter advertisements--each VRF will learn the routes of the other VRFs through the common VRF.

BGP would make more sense since it allows you to control what routes you advertise.  But there are still two major drawbacks:

1. You would need an additional router for inter-VRF routing.
2. The BGP configuration won't be any easier (simpler) than static route leaking.

Maybe someone else can think of a better way, but given your requirements, route leaking makes the most sense.

Comment: Even if it could ultimately result in 100s of static routes on the core switch ?

Comment: Yes, because you're going to have 3 or 4 configuration lines per VRF -- the same or more as if you used static routes

Comment: You can look into dynamic route leaking using MP-BGP.  http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/multiprotocol-label-switching-mpls/multiprotocol-label-switching-vpns-mpls-vpns/47807-routeleaking.html